# When refer to a graph, the label becomes lower case

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats, subcaption

I am trying to use subfigure pack to include multiple images in one figure. However, as shown in the following picture, 
[image]

When I try to refer to Figure 1A, it gives me the lower case 'a' but not 'A'. How may I solve this problem? A minimum working example is provided below.

```
\documentclass[english, 9pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}            % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{picinpar}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fixltx2e,amsmath}
\MakeRobust{\eqref}
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\fbox{}}


\title{example}





\begin{document}




refer to Figure \ref{fig:Clean}

 \begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Clean}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:Clean}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{noise_tank}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:Noisy_tank}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{}
\label{fig:fake_higher_jump}
\end{figure}




\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `amsart` uses a small-caps font to typeset the label of figures in captions, which is why `Figure 1` is in small-caps, for example. However, this does not change the standard representation of the counter. The counter still has value `1` for this figure. For numbers, this won't usually matter. However, since `subfigure`s use lower-case letters in their counters, it will: the label in the caption will be in small-caps, but references will show the standard representation of the counter in lower-case.

One way to alter this is to redefine `\thefigure` to use the appropriate font. I'm not sure that this is the best way to do this, but it does seem to work in at least the minimal case I tested.

## *Caveat emptor ...*

I started by minimising your example to figure out what was responsible for the behaviour. It is a long time since I used an AMS class and, even then, I actually used a parasitic class based on an AMS class, which may have redefined things. In any case, my document did not include any figures or tables.

Most of the preamble turned out to be irrelevant, so I deleted it. This left a short preamble including `amsart` with no options, `subfigure`, `graphicx` and the redefinition of `\includegraphics`. (You could drop the graphics stuff and just put a box or a word in the figures instead, but I didn't bother.

Here's the amended minimised example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\fbox{}}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\textsc{\alph{subfigure}}}
\begin{document}
refer to Figure \ref{fig:Clean}

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Clean}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:Clean}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{noise_tank}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:Noisy_tank}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:fake_higher_jump}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: references matching labels]

Comment: Note that `!h` is not advisable at all. What is LaTeX to do if it cannot put the figure right here?

Comment: So instead of !h, what should I put there? I just try to fix my image at the right place... although they never at the right place...

Comment: A `figure` is a float. Its purpose is to float to the place LaTeX thinks best. A `table` is similar. If you don't want it to float, don't use a float. You can use `\captionof{figure}{<caption>}` if you need a caption, since this is provided by the `caption` package.